# Error while deserializing intermediate XML. Cannot find type

Tags: c#, xml, xna

The whole error message is here:

```
There was an error while deserializing intermediate XML. Cannot find type
"WindowsGame1.Tile".
```

I'm making an XNA game, and right now I'm trying to load in a tile-based level from an xml file. Right now, my xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XnaContent>
  <Asset Type="WindowsGame1.Tile">
    <Tile>
      <X>0</X>
      <Y>0</Y>
      <ImageName>grass-tile</ImageName>
    </Tile>
  </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

And my C# file looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace WindowsGame1
{
    public class Tile
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public string imageName;

        public int X
        {
            get { return x; }
            set { x = value; }
        }

        public int Y
        {
            get { return y; }
            set { y = value; }
        }
        public string ImageName
        {
            get { return imageName; }
            set { imageName = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a class that uses the XPath libraries to parse the xml file and make Tile's out of it, but it's all commented out right now because the xml stuff doesn't work anyways. In my Game1 class I tried importing:

```
using WindowsGame1.Tile;
```

and referencing:

```
Tile tile;
```

This tile class, as per a suggestion I found while trying to find a solution to this, but I'm still getting the same error, and my game won't build. Anyone know what I need to change to get this XML stuff working?

Here's what the code that should be parsing the XML should look like, though at the moment, it's all commented out until I can get it to compile.

```
namespace WindowsGame1
{
    class ActionScreen : GameScreen
    {
        public ActionScreen(Game game, SpriteBatch spriteBatch, String file,  AnimatedSprite sprite)
            : base(game, spriteBatch)
        {
            this.file = file;
            this.sprite = sprite;
            initializeTiles();
        }

        private void initializeTiles()
        {
            XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(file);
            XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
            XPathNodeIterator iter = nav.Select("tile");

            while (iter.MoveNext())
            {
                int x, y;
                string fileName;

                x = int.Parse(iter.Current.GetAttribute("X", ""));
                y = int.Parse(iter.Current.GetAttribute("Y", ""));
                fileName = iter.Current.GetAttribute("ImageName", "");

                Console.WriteLine(x + " " + y + " " + fileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to parse XML manually. The content pipeline does it for you. See Andrew's answer and: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604981.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the XNA content pipeline to build the XML file as content - so my answer will skip all the XPath stuff you metioned - you don't need it.

The "deserializing" that the error is referring to is when the content pipeline is trying to convert your XML into **an object instance**. It then takes that object and writes it out to an XNB file. Later on, when your game runs it will load that XNB file back into **an object instance**.

An instance of which object? Well, in your case, a `WindowsGame1.Tile` object. How does the content pipeline *know* what a `WindowsGame1.Tile` object is? **It doesn't** - *not unless you tell it about it* - hence the error message.

---

**How do you fix this?**

You need to reference the assembly that contains the type `WindowsGame1.Tile` from your content pipeline project.

You can't reference your game project directly - because that would create a circular dependency (your game project already depends on the content project).

Therefore you must put the type `WindowsGame1.Tile` into a separate assembly (create a new "Game Library Project") that you reference from both your game project and your content project (right click the content project, add reference, add project reference).

Then you can load your tile in-game via the content manager:

```
Tile myTile = Content.Load<Tile>("assetName");
```

---

If you get another error about the *format* of your XML (I think I spy an error, but I haven't checked), you can figure out what it is supposed to be by creating a dummy instance of your `Tile` type, then use `IntermediateSerializer.Serialize` to generate the appropriate XML. [Here is an example of how to do this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/11241/288).

Comment: This was definitely the most useful answer, thanks! I managed to fix it by telling Visual Studio not to build the xml at all, and then my parsing stuff works just fine. I might change that though if there's a cleaner way to deal with xml.

Answer (score 0):

To make it deserialize properly, you have to have your properties names same in XML and in actual class. Try to rename property "imageName" to "image" in your Tile class.

Comment: try to use properties instead of fields. ex. public int x {get;set;} etc.

Comment: I also tried your smaller version of the properties ({get;set;}) with the non-capital letters in both the c# and xml files.

Comment: Try to add XmlElement attributes to your properties. Also can you please show how do you deserialize your XML and what error do you actually get?

Comment: I don't have anything for deserializing. I don't know what that means, and I can't find any good xml examples anywhere, explaining what it means or how to do it. I've added the error message to the top of my question.

EDIT: I also just tried adding an XmlElement, but that won't compile, so I'm probably doing it wrong. Updated code in question again.

Comment: Ok i see now. I thought you have different issue. Add please code of your class that uses XPath. Seems that problem there.

Comment: That code is all commented out currently, so it shouldn't be doing anything. I'll add what it looks like though.

Comment: You dont show actually code where the error occurs. The problem that there, where you're deserializing your xml, namespace WindowsGame1 is not acceseble or visible. Try to add usings there. Or, if it's in another project, add assembly reference.

Comment: The error seems to be a compile error. I can double click the error in Visual Studio, and it takes me to the Asset line of the XML. I did read that I needed to reference it somewhere, so I added a reference to Tile in my Game1 class, but they're in the same project, so I don't think I should have to do that.

I'm not doing anything to deserialize my xml, it's just happening (or rather not happening?) somewhere. I don't know what it means to deserialize it, and I can't find a good example anywhere. My goal is to get the xml into an array of Tiles in the ActionScreen class, so I can display them

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using `GetAttribute()` method instead doing a `Select("X").Value`. For example, instead of

```
x = int.Parse(iter.Current.GetAttribute("X", ""));
```

try

```
x = int.Parse(iter.Current.Select("X").Value, string.Empty));
```

You also may want to consider the System.Xml.Serlization.XmlSerializer class since it is easier to use but I do not know whether it is included in the version of the XNA framework you are using.

Comment: I'm using XNA 4.0. My issue is not with the parsing, that's commented out and not being used right now. My code won't compile anyways though, apparently because this xml file exists. If I delete the xml file, it runs perfectly fine, because nothing is referencing it. But once I add the xml file to the Content folder, it stops compiling.

Comment: There was an error while deserializing intermediate XML. Cannot find type "WindowsGame1.Tile".

Comment: OK. Are you using the full type name? Have a look at the assembly in ildasm and make sure it makes.

Comment: Should I be typing that into command prompt, with the .exe as a parameter? If so, that's not working. It says it's not recognized as a command/program/batch file. All my code is in my question, just copy-and-pasted.

Comment: No. I'm talking about using the full type name in the Type attribute for the Asset element.

Comment: Tile is the whole type name, in the namespace WindowsGame1. I don't know what could be missing.

Comment: It is hard to tell. However, similar questions have been asked before in the gamedev section of stack exchange like http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11230/how-to-use-xml-files-as-content-files-in-xna. It is not your exact problem but there are links there that may help.

Comment: Yeah that's the only question I could find that was even a bit similar to the problem I was having.. Thanks though. I suppose I'll keep looking.