# Layered Sprites With Predetermined Offset / Rotation

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, xna-4.0

Probably not a very descriptive title, but I'm doing my best.  It's my first time posting on StackOverflow, and I'm relatively new to programming in C# (first started around a year ago using Unity, and decided a few days ago to upgrade to XNA).  That being said, please be kind to me.

I'm planning out the mechanics of a 2D game that I'm designing, and while most of it seems straightforward after playing around in XNA, there's one issue that I keep coming back to that I have yet to come up with a satisfactory answer for.  The issue involves the layering of sprites into composite / complex sprites.  For example, a character in the game might be wielding one or two of any number of weapons.  I did do a bit of research on the topic, and found some people recommending to use the RenderTarget class to draw a series of sprites as one, and some recommending simply drawing the sprites on top of one another during Draw().  These topics, however, were mostly focused on the relatively simple case of having a single character in the game.

In my case, the game will have a number of sprite-based characters who have totally different postures / animations.  There are around 10 right now, and there will probably be more added later in development.  There will likewise be a largish number of weapons (probably around 20 to start) that will be composited onto the characters.  That much I'm comfortable with.  However, the problem is that each of the characters would require the weapon sprites to be draw in different locations and with different rotations during each frame of a character's animation.

I've considered a couple approaches to how to pull this off, but they all have pretty massive drawbacks.
The first was simply drawing a spritesheet of each weapon for each character, that would be the same size as the appropriate character.  The benefit to this approach would be the ease of just adding the call to draw the additional sprite on top of the base character without having to do any calculations.  The downside would be that that creates an inordinate amount of extra sprite sheets (200 extra sheets for 10 characters x 20 weapons).

The second was creating a class to handle the weapon sprite.  The WeaponSprite class would be attached to a single texture for each weapon, and would then store information about the offset / rotation to use when drawn, based on the character that it is attached to.  The problem with this is that organizing the offsets / rotations on a per-frame basis would be incredibly tedious, and I can't think of any easy way to pull the information based on the frame required.  (I had the idea of making an AnimationFrame class to keep track of the animation name, directional facing and frame number of each character, and then using a dictionary in the weapon class to load the proper data based on the name of the current frame, but something about the idea seemed really ill-conceived).  This method also has the drawback of requiring a relatively large amount of memory to pull off (assuming a Vector2 is 8 bytes and a float is 4, having 10 characters and 20 weapons would require 192KB of memory given the current number of frames being used, which would only get larger as more weapons were added).  I had an offshoot of that idea (which I sort of stole from another post on here about the same topic) of using a reserved alpha value pixel to link the offset and the 'origin' of each weapon, calculating the position at runtime and then only having to store the rotational float in the aforementioned dictionary.

Since I'm new to XNA (and still pretty green on C#), I figured I'd post and let the experts chime in.  Am I on the right track with my methods, or am I missing something really simple?  Thank you very much in advance for your help, and please let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, big question. I can't really tell you exactly how to implement this. But I can give you some helpful nuggets of advice:

**Advice #0:** Whenever any kind of compositing problem comes up, people come out of the woodwork recommending "render targets" as some kind of compositing panacea. They are usually wrong. Avoid using render targets if you can. You only need them if you are doing effects on the final, composite image (blends, blurs, etc). Otherwise just draw your sprites over the top of each other directly to the backbuffer.

**Advice #1:** You want to pack ***all*** your sprites onto a single sprite sheet, if possible. If you exceed the texture size limit, you'll have to be clever about how you partition your sprites across sheets. The reason is performance - you want to limit the number of texture swaps - [see this answer for details](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9289/288).

You may be able to use an existing sprite-packer for XNA. If you can find a suitable one, I recommend you use it. A good one will allow you to treat a packed sprite just as you would treat a texture when calling `SpriteBatch.Draw`.

**Advice #2:** Do not worry about how much space your positioning data takes at runtime. 192kb is almost nothing - the size of a small texture.

The upshot of this, and #1, is to store as much as possible in your positioning meta-data, and avoid duplicate textures.

*How* you store your meta-data almost doesn't matter.

**Advice #3:** You can change both your storage requirements and content creation story from an **n × m** problem to an **n + m** problem (n characters and m weapons). Simply store weapons with only an "origin", and store characters with an "origin" and a "hand position & rotation". Simply render such that the origin of the weapon lines up with the hand of the character (the maths is very simple).

Then you can add characters without worrying about what weapons exist, and add weapons without worrying about what characters exist.

Here's an example of how much space this needs: 10 characters × 20 bytes + 20 weapons × 8 bytes = 360 bytes. Nice and small! (Although you'll probably want many more attachment points - different kinds for different weapons, hats, whatever. Edit: oops I didn't include animation frames - but it's still a relatively small amount of data.)

**Advice #4:** The trickiest part, as you seem to be hinting at in your post, is content creation.

As you hint at, ideally you would want to be able to edit the attachment points directly in your image editor. This is a compelling idea. Special alpha values are only appropriate if your sprites have no anti-aliasing. You could theoretically do something with layers and different colours. The hardest part is figuring out how to encode rotation.

You could use an XNA content pipeline processor to extract data from the image at build-time. **However** this gets very expensive to implement (especially if you've not done it before - the content pipeline is badly under-documented). Unless your art requirements are truly enormous, it is almost certainly not worth the extra development time required to make the content pipeline extension. By the time you're done, you could have hand-coded the positioning data several times over.

My recommendation, then, is to store the extra data in an easy-to-edit XML file. I recommend using XNA's XML Content Importer. It can be tricky to get the hang of the [formatting](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/11241/288) at first, and you have to remember to include the appropriate [assembly referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12257534/165500). But once you know how to use it, it's the easiest way to get structured data into XNA quickly.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the post!  I guess I'll respond to each point in turn.

Comment: Can't edit after 5 minutes...?  Anyway, a lot of this was pretty helpful; I now know not to bother with the content pipeline right now if I don't have to.  Because of the sprites / weapons involved I feel like it would be ineffective to store the rotational data on the character, since it could easily change by the weapon as well as by the character, but it doesn't matter that much in terms of data I presume.  I guess I was just a little too worried about how memory usage would add up, and felt that 192kb was a bit large.  I'll look into XNA and plan on doing a single spritesheet at some point